# Can I "Exclude Values" of a dependent picklist if I deploy via a Change set?

Tags: deployment, picklist, field-dependencies

I am trying to deploy two picklist fields via Change Set Management, so that I can get the new changes(Include Values/Exclude Values) in the Field Dependency. After the deployment what I found was: New `Include Values` were successfully deployed, but the `Exclude Values` (also the values which are currently included), have not changed.

**Findings**: I have all the newly `Include Values` moved over, but the excluded values from the source org. doesn't really excluded any values on the destination org.. Thus old values still remain at the destination along with my newly included values.

**Questions**:

1. Do I need to manually exclude the values after my deployment?
2. Is there any other way I can deploy the Field Dependency(seperately) along with the two Picklist fields?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit that how did you *Exclude* a value from the picklist in the Change Set?

Comment: Not an actual Picklist value, but the field dependency value(Picklist dependency). And when I say Excluded from the source, I mean: I have updated the field dependencies by including/excluding dependency field values on the Source org.

Comment: That helps. So you changed the "dependency" between the two fields and that you are trying to deploy both fields using a change set, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. I have deployed both the fields.

Comment: I found this [**post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193445/dependent-picklist-configuration-not-deploying) around similar issue. And seems that it is not supported. Refer to the comment dated 7/27 on the question.

Comment: This is so annoying. Also there is no point of deployment at all, if it covers only the inclusions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered your first question on your own. The best way to find out if it can be brought over via a change set is to try. If it doesn't work you'll have to do it manually.

As for the second question, there's a ton of different migration tools out there that could probably migrate the differences without the need to manually remove values in your destination org. Gearset for instance, does a full meta-data compare and allows you to select which meta-data you want to deploy. This would make it very clear what the end result of the deployment will be and should allow you to remove the unwanted values. Gearset does cost money though.

Infact, most of these extra tools would take a little bit of implementation work. If you're only having issues with this one deployment it may not be worth it. Personally, I love gearset (not affiliated). If you're looking for migration tool I'd make sure to put the effort into researching your options and deciding whats best for you.

Comment: While what you have mentioned is helpful, but I think you can improve this answer by providing some references from documentation or some test results. In its current form, I feel it does not really address OP's actual issue. Usually in these type of questions where there is no real documentation or evidence available, my approach is to provide some test results and form the answer based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple trick to deploy dependent fields that are set from Include to Exclude using a package. With the dependent field set to "Exclude" on the dependency matrix simply deactivate and reactivate the (Excluded) picklist field value(s) from associated record type. Then retrieve your package again and when you deploy it will remove the fields from the dependent picklist. HTH's . We were doing this manually but no more.